# jquery.min and ajax Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, ajax, conflict

I use ajax script on site (smartajax) to load pages,
But for some reason it crushes on some pages.
firebug says the problem this function in jquery.min v 1.5.2:

`noop: function(){},
globalEval: function(a) {
if (a && i.test(a)) {var b = c.head || c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || c.documentElement,
e = c.createElement("script");d.support.scriptEval()? e.appendChild(c.createTextNode(a)) : e.text = a,b.insertBefore(e,b.firstChild), b.removeChild(e)}},nodeName: function (a, b) {return a.nodeName && a.nodeName.toUpperCase() === b.toUpperCase()},`
When i remove this function pages not crush,But also ajax not working well???

and here how i call ajax:

```
SmartAjax_load('js/smartajax/', function(){SmartAjax.isDebug = false;SmartAjax.setOptions({cache: false,reload:false,containers[{selector: '#container'}],before:function({jQuery('#ajaxloader').show();SmartAjax.proceed();},done:function({jQuery('#ajaxloader').hide();}});SmartAjax.bind('a[rel=zcommunity]');}, true);
```

Please where is the error or any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an incompatibility between jQuery 1.5.2 and SmartAjax.  You can try upgrading to jQuery 1.7.1 but, personally, I would just use the built in [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) functions.  Is there a reason you have to use SmartAjax?

Comment: Thank you for replay.... but really i tried everything....smartajax the only one i could use (am using Social engine v3).